# add or remove options from createChooser

Tags: android

```
String message = "Text I want to share";
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share on"));
```

right now it shows the default options like: `Bluetooth, Email, Facebook, Gmail, LinkedIn, Messaging, Share Via Barcode.`

or are these the installed apps?

what i want is to know, how i can remove few from this list. like i want to remove `Share Via Barcode`.

and add something else?

Thank You

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use below code to add a new Item to the Chooser Screen.

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");       
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

Intent addIntent = ;//whatever you want

Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, share );      
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "title");

Intent[] intentArray =  {addIntent }; 
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
startActivity(chooser);
```

But removing specific items is not possible. So you could resolve the intent using [Packagemanager.resolveActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and create your own custom list view

Comment: i mean you didn't add this in the code: "chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);" i just want to know whether you forgot or that its no possible this way

Comment: no it needs to be in the share intent. share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message); and not in the chooser

Comment: fine. thanks a lot. so i get i better use a custom submenu to have just what all options i want. But how can i get the implementation?

Comment: i mean like, in the submenu i want to add messaging and something else. how can i make messaging work just like the one i am getting right now?

Comment: You could actually use chooser also, you can pass a long list of all intents in intentArray in the code i pasted

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15761/discussion-between-nandeesh-and-archie-bpgc)

Answer (score 3):

I used the following code to get a list of all eMail and SMS apps installed on the device:

```
Intent shareSMS = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("smsto", "12346556", null));
shareSMS.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
shareSMS.putExtra("sms_body", message);

Intent shareEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "", null));
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> mailActivityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareEmail, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

List<Intent> mailIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
for (ResolveInfo resInfo : mailActivityList) {
    Intent targetedOpenIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "", null))
            .setPackage(resInfo.activityInfo.packageName)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emails)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    mailIntents.add(targetedOpenIntent);
}

Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, shareSMS);
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Send request");
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, mailIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] { }));

startActivity(chooser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding Option to chooser

```
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");       
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

            Intent extraOptionToAdd = new Intent(this, ExtraOptionActivity.class);
            extraOptionToAdd.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
            LabeledIntent labeledExtraOption = new LabeledIntent(extraOptionToAdd, getPackageName(), "Extra Option!", 0);

            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Now!");
            Intent[] intentArray =  {labeledExtraOption};
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivity(chooser);
```